# Network daig ns* project in openshift is struck in terminating mode

Tags: openshift

Due to some maintenance our network was shut down for some time, after we restarted the openshift service the deployments getting failed with 137 error after some debugging i came to know that network-diag-ns* projects in OKD are struck in terminating mode. Is it safe to delete those projects, Can some one please suggest safer method to restore the projects, i tried to delete those projects but its not deleting, as I am new to openshift any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because something is preventing a resource from being deleted, causing namespace deletion to be stuck. It is necessary to troubleshoot which resources are failing to be deleted and why.

You may try to run the command `oc api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -t -n 1 oc get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n <YOUR_STUCK_PROJECT>` in order to see what resources are still keeping the namespace busy and try to delete them.